# Importing 2 applications and a common Library project in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have 3 eclipse android projects (ProjectLib, App1 and App2) which I want to import in android studio. Project ProjectLib is a library project and other two are applications using the ProjectLib. App1 and App2 are almost identical apps like a free and paid version and mainly most of the code resides in the ProjectLib

**Expected Structure of Projects in IDE**

So i have been working them all three open at the same time in Eclipse under a single Eclipse workspace and the end result was 2 APks generated for my two apps.

**Steps I performed**

I have successfully imported the ProjectLib in the android studio using Import Project .. after this when I go to File ->new-> Import project..  and open the App1 and press finish on the import window it opens a new instance of android studio and now opens 2 modules in there App1 and ProjectLib.

Now I end up with two instances of android studio ProjectLib done in first step and then another instance with App1 and ProjectLib..

I need your advise as to how can I keep the 2 apps and 1 Lib in the same project and then be able to generate 2 Apks in a single build..

Thanks,